# CASE expression - add one more condition to the WHEN part

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created a PL/SQL function where I have a `case` expression in a SQL query. This is working fine, but when I add another `when` condition it will not compile. Even if I use `when ... and 2 > 1`, this is also not compiling.

In the below code, the commented part is not working properly.

What I want is to add one more check in my `when` clause. Please advise.

```
create or replace function FUNCTION_NAME (date1 in varchar2,value1 in varchar2)
    RETURN date
IS
  date2 date;
BEGIN 
  SELECT D DATE2
    INTO DATE2 FROM (SELECT CASE (SELECT TO_DATE(MAX(G.DATE3),'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                    FROM TABLE1 G,
                                         TABLE2 N
                                    WHERE G.DATE3=N.DATE3)
                              WHEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(DATE1,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
                                   /* AND MONTHS_BETWEEN (LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(SYSDATE)),
                                      LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE1),'DD-MON-YYYY'))) */
                                THEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(DATE1,'DD-MON-YYYY'))

                              ELSE
                                TO_DATE('31-DEC-99','DD-MON-YYYY')
                            END D
                       FROM DUAL);

  RETURN DATE2;
END;
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your keyboard, your caps-lock or shift key seems stuck. Or just please stop shouting at us.

Comment: Sure Bro , Pls Try to Help on the Programming Question :)

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags the site adds to your post; often the defaults are pretty random. I just deleted the references to sql developer and plsql developer, which have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Hi @vaibhavsaini and welcome to SO. Asking your question politely is a good way to get more help. You can edit your question to get rid of the ALL CAPS.

Comment: More clarification on terminology: CASE **statements** do exist, similar to `if... then...` and in a CASE **statement** you can have an SQL query, etc. This is NOT what you have in your code. In your code you have an SQL query, in which you have a CASE **expression**.

Comment: `MONTHS_BETWEEN` is a function which returns a number, so you need to compare the results of `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to a number somewhere. You've just got it hanging there with no comparison. Same thing for `LAST_DAY` - you need to compare the result of `LAST_DAY` to a number at some point.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a case expression (not a case statement).

Case expressions are of two kinds: "simple" (`case <expr> when val1 then ... when val2 then...` etc.) and "searched" ( `case when condition1 then ... when condition2 then ...` etc.)

You wrote your case expression as a simple case expression. You can't, then, add conditions to the WHEN part. You must change the case expression to be "searched" all the way through.

```
case when (select ...) = last_day(...) AND <your commented condition> THEN .....
```

**EDIT** - copying part of a clarifying comment below my Answer.

Simple case expression:

```
case x when 1 then ....
```

Can also be written as searched case expression:

```
case when x = 1 then ....
```

These two are logically equivalent. However, if we want to add "AND 3 > 1" to the WHEN part, that works only in the **searched** form of the case expression.

Comment: Can You Reframe the COde and Send Please  ??? Are you Suggesting to Use CASE again with When Condition , because I do not want to use SQL query there rather i am just checking case of SQL Expression O/P

Comment: @vaibhavsaini - no, what I show is INSTEAD OF what you have. The word WHEN must come immediately after the word CASE. The equality of the scalar subquery to the LAST_DAY... must be written explicitly (with an equal sign, = ) so it is a logical condition which can be operated upon by the logical operator AND, so you can add a second condition. For example: `case x when 1 then...` works. `case x when 1 and 3 > 1 then...` doesn't work, as you saw; it must be `case when x = 1 and 3 > 1 then...`

Comment: Thanks mathguy for explaining in detail. Really appreciate your write up... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are [two flavours of `CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96).

Simple CASE:

```
select case dummy
            when 'X' then 1
       end as case_demo
from dual;
```

Searched CASE:

```
select case
            when dummy = 'X' then 1
       end as case_demo
from   dual;
```

In your query you are mixing them like this, which won't work:

```
select case dummy
            when 'X' and 1 = 1
            then 1
       end as case_demo
from   dual;
```

If you switch to a "searched CASE", then you can add more `when` conditions:

```
select case
            when dummy = 'X' and 1 = 1
            then 1
       end as case_demo
from   dual;
```

Comment: Thanks William Robertson for explaining in detail. Really appreciate your write up... Thanks

Comment: Thanks William Robertson for explaining in detail. Really appreciate your write up... Thanks